# Obtaining the F and p-values from lm() in R

Tags: r

Given a regression, undertaken in R;  namely :

```
 regfit  <- lm(y ~ x, cricketData)
```

with the last line of `summary(regfit)` being :

```
  F-statistic: 29.97 on 1 and 13 DF,  p-value: 0.0001067
```

is it possible to obtain merely the values of the F-statistic and the p-value?

```
  summary (regfit)$fstatistic[1]
```

returns  :| value|  which is not what I intend. | 29.97|

Similarly for `print (pf(Fstat[1], Fstat[2], Fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE))` which
prints the p-value beneath the word "value".

Is it possible to obtain the numeric value per se or is there a means to repress the world "value" and obtain the numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

It is a named `vector`.  Just do `unname` to remove the name `value`

```
unname(pf(Fstat[1], Fstat[2], Fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE))
```

similarly

```
unname(summary (regfit)$fstatistic[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `broom::glance()`:

```r
example("lm") ## to define lm.D90
library("broom")
glance(lm.D90)[,c("statistic", "p.value")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply extract the value without the name:

```
summary(regfit)$fstatistic[[1]]
```

For the p-value:

```
pf(Fstat[[1]], Fstat[2], Fstat[3], lower.tail=FALSE)
```